# How to disambiguate the overloads of the `erase_all_if` function template?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++17, sfinae

I have two implementations of the `erase_all_if`function template.

```
template <typename Container, typename Pred>
typename Container::size_type erase_all_if(Container& c, Pred&& pred)
{
    auto newend = std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), std::forward<Pred>(pred));
    auto ret = c.end() - newend;
    c.erase(newend, c.end());
    return ret;
}

template <typename Container, typename Pred>
auto erase_all_if(Container& c, Pred&& pred) {
    typename Container::size_type removed = 0;
    for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end();) {
        if (pred(*it)) {
            it = c.erase(it);
            ++removed;
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
    return removed;
}
```

The first works only for containers like `std::vector` because it requires a random access iterator and the second one for all containers, but it is more inefficient for continuous containers and it is appropriate for node-based containers. How to disambiguate the two versions? The C++ standard I'm currently using is C++17.

Comment: only one of the two functions would suffice, but please do not remove the includes from the code. A example of instantiating them would also help to get something working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need SFINAE here. I would combine the two functions into one, and do

```
if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<std::random_access_iterator_tag,
    typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(c.begin())>::iterator_category>)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

Or you can use tag dispatch: (note that iterator categories inherit from each other, so this handles fallback between categories nicely)

```
template <typename Container, typename Pred>
typename Container::size_type erase_all_if_low(std::random_access_iterator_tag, Container& c, Pred&& pred)
{
    // ...
}

template <typename Container, typename Pred>
typename Container::size_type erase_all_if_low(std::forward_iterator_tag, Container& c, Pred&& pred)
{
    // ...
}

template <typename Container, typename Pred>
auto erase_all_if(Container& c, Pred &&pred)
{
    using category = typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(c.begin())>::iterator_category;
    return erase_all_if_low(category{}, c, std::forward<Pred>(pred));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No SFINAE is needed here. You could use add a helper templates here that receive the interator category as additional parameter. You could even make this work with C++11 with some adjustments.

```
// helper templates with overloads taking a parameter indicating info about the iterator category
namespace impl
{

    template<class T>
    constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())>::iterator_category ContainerIteratorCategory_v {};

    template <typename Container, typename Pred>
    typename Container::size_type erase_all_if(std::random_access_iterator_tag, Container& c, Pred&& pred)
    {
        auto newend = std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), std::forward<Pred>(pred));
        auto ret = c.end() - newend;
        c.erase(newend, c.end());
        return ret;
    }

    template <typename Container, typename Pred>
    auto erase_all_if(std::input_iterator_tag, Container& c, Pred&& pred) {
        typename Container::size_type removed = 0;
        for (auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end();) {
            if (pred(*it)) {
                it = c.erase(it);
                ++removed;
            }
            else {
                ++it;
            }
        }
        return removed;
    }
}

template <typename Container, typename Pred>
auto erase_all_if(Container& c, Pred&& pred) {
    return impl::erase_all_if(impl::ContainerIteratorCategory_v<Container>, c, std::forward<Pred>(pred));
}

template<class Container>
void Print(Container const& c)
{
    for (auto& e : c)
    {
        std::cout << e << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    {
        std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        std::cout << "std::vector<int>: " << erase_all_if(v, [](int i) { return (i % 2) == 0; }) << '\n';
        Print(v);
    }
    {
        std::list<int> l{6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        std::cout << "std::list<int>: " << erase_all_if(l, [](int i) { return (i % 2) == 0; }) << '\n';
        Print(l);
    }
}
```